# How to add HTML with php

Tags: php, woocommerce

I'm working with WooCommerce and customized the pre-existing email templates to show the individual price as well..

The code I used to do that is

```
<td style="text-align:left; vertical-align:middle; border: 1px solid #eee;"><?php echo $order->get_item_total( $item ); ?></td>
```

Currently it only outputs the number with no "$". I tried putting:

```
<td style="text-align:left; vertical-align:middle; border: 1px solid #eee;"><?php echo "$" + $order->get_item_total( $item ); ?></td>
```

That doesn't work though.

What is the proper way of adding in the HTML?

Comment: It's casting `$` to `0` and adding it to the total.

Comment: Voting to close as this has minimal ongoing value to the community as this is simple problem of not knowing how to concatenate strings in PHP, something EASILY determined by reading the PHP documentation or any of hundreds of thousands of code samples on the web.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `.` for string concatenation, not `+`.

Like this: `<?php echo "$" . $order->get_item_total( $item ); ?>`.

One of the big differences between Javascript and PHP -- gets me all the time.

(or like this: `$<?php echo $order->get_item_total( $item ); ?>`)

Comment: Or move it out of the PHP tags.